# Lightbox does not close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I found a `lightbox` which I like but it does not close when I click around it. Neither can I load it onto my page, it only works when it is in my index. 
Can someone explain me, what I have to change? Maybe someone also used the same script and can help me out a little bit.

```js
     < script >
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.lightbox').click(function(e) {
          //prevent default action (hyperlink)
          e.preventDefault();

          //Get clicked link href
          var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

          /*  
  If the lightbox window HTML already exists in document, 
  change the img src to to match the href of whatever link was clicked
  
  If the lightbox window HTML doesn't exists, create it and insert it.
  (This will only happen the first time around)
  */

          if ($('#lightbox').length) { // #lightbox exists
            //place href as img src value
            $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');
            //show lightbox window - you could use .show('fast') for a transition
            $('#lightbox').show('slow');
          } else { //#lightbox does not exist - create and insert (runs 1st time only)

            //create HTML markup for lightbox window
            var lightbox =
              '<div id="lightbox">' +
              '<p>Click to close</p>' +
              '<div id="content">' + //insert clicked link's href into img src
              '<img src="' + image_href + '" />' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>';

            //insert lightbox HTML into page
            $('#stage').append(lightbox)
            $('.work').slideUp('slow');
          }

        });


        if ($('#lightbox')) {
          //Click anywhere on the page to get rid of lightbox window
          $('body').on('click', function() {
            $('#lightbox').remove();
            $('.work').slideDown('slow');
          });
        }
      }); < /script>
```

Comment: jQuery live is really outdated. Been deprecated for years and has been removed from the newest versions of jQuery. In your code you do not show how you link to the library or jQuery.

Comment: Oh sorry, it is linked as:     <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: well there you go, live is not supported in 2.X. And why are you including two versions of jQuery? Just include the min version.

Comment: You're binding a click event on `#lightbox` and trying to hide `#lightbox`? Shouldn't the click event be on `body`?

Comment: @epascarello you're right :D

Comment: @asprin then it closes direktly on the first click. But i guess it is possible to fix this with an if statement